# NodeJs routing directory with Angular 2 rc.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm working on my first a NodeJs + Angular 2 project. It worked perfectly fine without Angular2 in my previous projects with these kind of routes.

I got error on accessing multi-level directory routing in NodeJs.

Example:

It works in this way:

```
app.get('/dashboard', dashboard.getHome);        // works
app.get('/user', user.getUser);                  // works
```

Instead of:

```
app.get('/dashboard/home', dashboard.getHome);   // won't work
app.get('/user/home', user.getUser);             // won't work
```

I understand there's Angular2 routing to work with but is there anyway to directly access to the static URL which I specified in NodeJs?

I'll get error if I wanna access more than 1 level  like :

```
/dashboard/tasks/42
```

I'm not able to do it now and that's the problem I'm struggling with.

app.js

```
var main = require('./routes/index');
var dashboard = require('./routes/dashboard');
var user = require('./routes/user');

app.get('/', main.index);

app.get('/dashboard', dashboard.getHome);        // works
// app.get('/dashboard/home', dashboard.getHome);   // won't work this way

app.get('/user', user.getUser);                  // works
// app.get('/user/home', user.getUser);             // won't work this way
```

dashboard/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teamo - Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="javascripts/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    System.import('app/dashboard/dashboard').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-dashboard>Loading...</my-dashboard>
</body>
```

It won't work using this URL even if I've set the route below in app.js:

```
localhost:3000/dashboard/home
```

It returns the errors below.

Error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/javascripts/core-js/client/shim.min.js 
GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/javascripts/zone.js/dist/zone.js 
GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/javascripts/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js 
GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/javascripts/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 
GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/systemjs.config.js 
GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/js/pace.min.js 
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined(anonymous function) @ home:18
GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/js/pace.min.js 
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the elements:

```
 app.get('/dashboard', dashboard.getHome);        // works
 app.get('/dashboard/home', dashboard.getHome);   // won't work
```

to:

```
   app.get('/dashboard/home', dashboard.getHome);   // won't work
   app.get('/dashboard', dashboard.getHome);        // works
```

Express is sensitive to the order.

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm not clear with my question. I've edited my question with more details. The problem I'm actually facing is I'm not able to have route which is more than 1 level like I only can access route with 'localhost:3000/dashboard' instead of 'localhost:3000/dashboard/tasks/42'.
I couldn't access to any deeper than 'localhost:3000/dashboard'.

Comment: @Danzeeeee But have you tried changing the order of the elements so the parent directory is set after the subdirectory?